# Send Intent Each Day Using AlarmManager?

Tags: android, android-widget, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want the following:

- The AlarmManager sends a daily intent to my AppWidgetProvider at midnight EXACTLY.
- The Alarm must wake up the device.

Here is how I did it:

In my AppWidgetProvider subclass:

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Widget Provider enabled.  Starting timer");

    //Setting the Calender object to midnight time.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

    //The fired Intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE); //custom intent name
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24, pendingIntent);
}
```

Although I think I did it right, this code doesn't work!

To test it, I changed 1000*60*60*24 with 10000 (10 sec) and updated a textView in the widget with random number. The random number never changed.

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the problem !

It seems that I need to set the [`AM_PM`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#AM_PM) value too. When I print the calender using `getTime().toLocaleString()`, it was set to the next day but 12 hours later (12:00:00 **PM**).

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

This is a perfect setup for the [Calender](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) instance that will set the alarm to the next day at midnight (i.e. the nearest midnight). You just pass it to the [`setRepeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method.

Thanks @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2):

First, what you want is not strictly possible. Android is not a RTOS; you may not get control "at midnight EXACTLY"

Second, your `Calendar` object represents a time in the past (unless it happens to be midnight at the time you are executing that code, in which case it represents the present). Try a start time in the future.

Comment: After I read the code, I found that my Calender object represent the current time. I used `add` not `set`. So, if this is the case, I am supposed to `SET Hour, Min and Sec to zero and ADD 1 to DAY_OF_MONTH` ?

Comment: @iturki: "I used add not set." -- I made the same mistake, thinking you were using `set()`. "if this is the case, I am supposed to..." -- yes, for midnight, that should work to give you tomorrow's midnight.

Comment: I'll give it a try and wait for midnight to pass!

Comment: @iturki: Or, test it on an emulator and change the emulator's time to a few minutes before midnight.

Comment: Didn't work in the emulator! I even tried setting `HOUR` to 12. I waited for 5 mins after midnight and still no update at all. Any ideas why?

Comment: @iturki: `Calendar` is on a 24-hour clock. Midnight is `0`.

Comment: But still the alarm didn't go off at midnight even if I set `HOUR` to 0